# Scrapy crawling with jquery search

Tags: python, html, scrapy

I'm trying to extract some information from site https://www.moparpartsgiant.com/ using product numbers. List some of them ['5175788AA', '82214506AB', 'UN051D1AA'].
Search responses are .html files with this products and they have chaotic urls so I can't run spider with changing only part of url.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JEVm.png)
I tryed run crawling through scrapy.FormRequest:

```
def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
    yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                           formdata={'input_name': '5175788AA'},
                                           callback=self.parse_product
                                           )
```

But I can't set `input_name` because `form` `input` doesn't have tag argument `name`.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dIDt.png)

How can I run search using scrapy.FormRequest? Or how can I simulate the `request` that is doing the search?

Thanks in advance for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Generated urls along with information aaren't dynamic using the above keywords but the clicking on the search option is dynamic.If you search by input keyword manually then you will get url for searching. So you can feed all urls and can scrape the required data. The same thing you can do automatically using selenium/playwright which are time consuming and more complex but may not be easy task with scrapy

**Working code with an example:**

```
import scrapy

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    
    urls = [
        'https://www.moparpartsgiant.com/parts/mopar-2-way~5175788aa.html',
        'https://www.moparpartsgiant.com/parts/mopar-accessories_bag_kit_storage-82214506ab.html',
        'https://www.moparpartsgiant.com/parts/mopar-a-c-duct-left~un051d1aa.html'
    ]


    def start_requests(self): 
        for url in self.urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_details)

    def parse_details(self, response):

        data = []

        d = {x.css('span::text').get() : x.css('span+div::text').get() for x in response.css('ul.pn-detail-list li')}
        yield d
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    process =CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(TestSpider)
    process.start()
```

**Output:**

```
2022-10-06 03:49:51 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.moparpartsgiant.com/parts/mopar-accessories_bag_kit_storage-82214506ab.html>
{}
2022-10-06 03:49:51 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.moparpartsgiant.com/parts/mopar-a-c-duct-left~un051d1aa.html> (referer: None)
2022-10-06 03:49:51 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.moparpartsgiant.com/parts/mopar-2-way~5175788aa.html>
{'Part Description': 'Wiring Kit 2 Way Female', 'Replaced By': '5175788AB', 'Manufacturer': 'Mopar'}
2022-10-06 03:49:51 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.moparpartsgiant.com/parts/mopar-a-c-duct-left~un051d1aa.html>
{'Part Description': 'Vent A/C Duct Left', 'Position': 'Left', 'Replaced By': '5179768AA', 'Manufacturer': 'Mopar'}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. The dynamic search is my problem, becouse input few million keywords manually is not the option :( It works with Selenium, but it take too many time. I'm trying find out how to simulate the request after push search button.